# npm error: internalBinding is not defined

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have followed some similar solutions but nothing has helped. This is what happened for me.

I had previously installed the latest version of npm a month ago. Now, I tried to run a npm script for the setup of something. I ran the code `npm install npm@3.3.12 -g`. This installed another version of npm. Now, I can't install or not even uninstall npm because of this error.

Also, I can see those two versions of npm/node in error as well

```
v11.6.0
v3.3.12
```

Please let me know if you have any idea. Any help will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to remove node completely and then reinstall.